# WHERE Clause with STUFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to do a query, that I get some ID an separate then with commas, and put it on my `where` clause.

But occurs the following error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2998,2999,3000,3001,3002,3003,3004,3005,3006,3007,3008,3009,3010,3011,3012,3013,3482,3483,3484,3485,3486,3487,3488,3489,3490,3491,3492,3493,3494,3495,...

I tried some cast, but doesn't work.

Sample query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.ID_PERIODO_GESTAO, A.ID_FILIAL, A.ID_RESPONSAVEL_AREA, A.ID_PARENT, A.ID_SOURCE, A.COD_AREA, A.DESC_AREA, A.ATIVO, A.USER_LOGIN_RESP, A.NOME_RESP, A.DESC_FILIAL, A.COD_AREA_SUP, A.FOTO_PATH, 
A.COLABORADOR_ID,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(B.ID_COLABORADOR) FROM COLABORADOR_AREA B WHERE B.ID_AREA = A.ID GROUP BY B.ID_AREA) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
(SELECT COUNT(B.ID_COLABORADOR) FROM COLABORADOR_AREA B WHERE B.ID_AREA = A.ID GROUP BY B.ID_AREA) END AS QTD_COLABORADORES,
A.LEVEL_TREE,LEN(A.LEVEL_TREE),

STUFF(
           (SELECT ',' + CAST(VW.ID AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM VW_AREA VW
            WHERE LEN(VW.LEVEL_TREE) > LEN(A.LEVEL_TREE) 
            AND VW.ID_PERIODO_GESTAO = 2                 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

FROM VW_AREA A
LEFT JOIN dbo.COLABORADOR_AREA ON dbo.COLABORADOR_AREA.ID_COLABORADOR = A.COLABORADOR_ID        
WHERE A.ID_FILIAL IN (9) AND A.ID_PERIODO_GESTAO = 2

UNION

SELECT A.ID, A.ID_PERIODO_GESTAO, A.ID_FILIAL, A.ID_RESPONSAVEL_AREA, A.ID_PARENT, A.ID_SOURCE, A.COD_AREA, A.DESC_AREA, A.ATIVO, A.USER_LOGIN_RESP, A.NOME_RESP, A.DESC_FILIAL, A.COD_AREA_SUP, A.FOTO_PATH, 
A.COLABORADOR_ID,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(B.ID_COLABORADOR) FROM COLABORADOR_AREA B WHERE B.ID_AREA = A.ID GROUP BY B.ID_AREA) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
(SELECT COUNT(B.ID_COLABORADOR) FROM COLABORADOR_AREA B WHERE B.ID_AREA = A.ID GROUP BY B.ID_AREA) END AS QTD_COLABORADORES,
A.LEVEL_TREE, LEN(A.LEVEL_TREE),

    STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' + CAST(VW.ID AS VARCHAR(10))
             FROM VW_AREA VW 
             WHERE LEN(VW.LEVEL_TREE) > LEN(A.LEVEL_TREE) 
             AND VW.ID_PERIODO_GESTAO = 2           
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS 

FROM VW_AREA A
LEFT JOIN dbo.COLABORADOR_AREA ON dbo.COLABORADOR_AREA.ID_COLABORADOR = A.COLABORADOR_ID
JOIN CTE4 ON A.ID = CTE4.ID_PARENT
WHERE A.ID_PERIODO_GESTAO = 2 
AND (A.ID IN (CTE4.ID_PARENT))
```

**RESULT**

```
QTD_COLABORATOR    LEVEL_TREE     QTD_CARACTER_IN_LEVEL_TREE
1                  002            3
```

The last column, with the STUFF function, will contains data like that

`2997,2998,2999,3000,3001,3002,3003,3004,3005,3006,3007,3008,3009,3010,3011,3012,3013,3014,3015,3016,3017`

This is all ID that contains more then 3 caracter in LEVEL_TREE

Comment: Could you provide us some sample values for ID stored in your VW_AREA view?

Comment: You don't have an alias for the last column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will never work. You're trying to use an in comparator against a string. Hence the syntax error. Is there a reason you can't do this?

```
SELECT SUM(A.ID) 
 FROM COLABORATOR A 
 WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT VW.ID FROM VW_AREA VW)
```

Comment: I updated my query, and now I can show you that is not to simple like that. Unfortunelly.

Comment: The updated SQL doesn't make a whole lot of sense compared with your initial problem. It has some obvious unrelated syntax errors and doesn't show the problem you initially described. Can you please recheck this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi STUFF will make your values comma separated, and the IN Clause will expect a Result Set of INTs, so there it crashes,
You might be able to do it with Dynamic String execution like this:

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = ' + @city
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```